# Does Chrome conform to CSS table specifications?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I was styling up a server generated table with some CSS (I'm trying to prove that Telerick controls are overrated, but that's a different discussion).

Any way, the tables look great in IE8 and Firefox and are styled exactly as I would expect. However, the table looks awful in Chrome. Don't get me wrong, Chrome is a great browser, and what I usually use; however, it may be lacking in the particular aspect.

So basically what I am asking is: Does Chrome have problems with CSS and tables or am I just poor at CSS (while IE and Firefox correctly anticipated my weakness)?

UPDATE: the problem is that the table (set to width: 100%) is overrunning its parent container which has the border to pretty the whole thing up. Additionally, the pager row at the bottom has it's border top property set to "dotted", yet it is solid on one of the columns!?

```
/*-------------Grid------------*/
table.grid
{
    width: 100%;
}

.grid tr th
{
    background-color: #696969;
    background-image: url('/Images/grid-bg.png');
    color: White;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: left;
}

.grid td, .grid th
{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.grid th a:hover, .grid th a:link
{
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid th a:hover
{
    background-color: #696969;
}

.grid tr.even
{
    background-color: #EBF2FC;
}

div.grid
{
    border: 1px solid #5D7FA6;
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 1px;
}

.pager
{
    border-top:  1px dotted #5D7FA6;
}

.data-row
{
    height: 24px;
}

.grid tr.data-row:hover
{
    color:White;
    background-color: #5D7FA6;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your code. You *might* be doing something wrong. Chrome *might* be doing something wrong.

Comment: Then again if there was something wrong enough for Google to fail all sorts of table CSS specifications, it would probably not get 100% on the acid3 test :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still difficult to tell you exactly what to change without seeing a [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/).

However.. try `box-sizing: border-box`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing

Add this to *something* (`table.grid`? `div.grid`?):

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: I don't really have to change anything since I am only required to support IE (which looks fine) haha
But any way does this go the surrounding box or the table itself?

Comment: Why would I want to add: -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
It already looks great in FF; the only browser with a problem is chrome

Comment: Well, the aim is to achieve *consistency*. Once it's consistent, you can adjust other things.

Comment: Ok, so I added -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; to the table and that fixed one of the the problems (although the pager border-top is still solid instead of dotted only on the right-most column).

But I am not marking this as an answer since my question was not "how can I fix this" :)

Comment: Did you look at the question I linked to a few comments ago? I have no clue about your other problem. A [demonstration of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help :)

Comment: So chrome is the only one that is right, as IE is j designed wrong and FF has a bug that makes it wrong when it comes to tables?

Comment: @badBadCoder - paste your HTML into validator.w3.org to check that it is all correctly structured. Having structural errors in your HTML is the most common cause of browsers being "flaky"

Comment: You're a little late to the party Stephen; we already pretty much established that I suck at CSS ;)

Comment: @badBadCoder: Chrome/Safari (the WebKit browsers) both behave in a way different to every other browser - but, I don't believe it's a bug. I think it's a choice that WebKit has purposely made. I don't *think* the spec specifies how the width should be calculated.